# What is the criteria for Top New Users in the User Leagues on StackExchange.com?

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues, stackexchange.com

As shown in a [recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/customizing-stackexchange-com/), the StackExchange.com page now has User Leagues for all of the sites.  One of the stats displayed is the top new users during the given period (week, month, quarter, year).  However, not all sites show this stat for all periods, so it seems the section is only shown if there are users that qualify.  I'm wondering what makes a new user considered as a *top new user* for a given period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the normal list, take the top 3 users who were created during this time period (e.g., "Week of Sep 6, 2010").  So the criteria are:

1. User was created during this time period
2. User earned reputation during this time period
3. User has more than 200 reputation *total*, since users with <200 reputation aren't tracked in the leagues

If you're seeing less than 3, most likely it's because none of the new users have crossed the 200 rep threshold yet.  It's possible that they'll show up in the future if they cross 200 reputation in a few weeks and start being tracked (we pull in their entire history).